# QueryFilter with multiple contain DynamoDb

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

i have document and this document stores system job. i want to get job list except i didnt want to get some job if job status contains CANCELED and CREATED words.

```
ItemCollection<QueryOutcome> items = index.query(new QuerySpec().withHashKey("deviceId", "string1")
        .withQueryFilters(new QueryFilter("currentState").notContains("CANCELED").notContains("CREATED")));
```

But this code returns also jobs with status = CANCELED .
I need some help. Could you pls?? :)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Query Spec with not contains for String attribute:-**

```
QuerySpec spec = new QuerySpec()
    .withKeyConditionExpression("deviceId = :v_id") 
    .withFilterExpression("not(contains(currentState, :version) or contains(currentState, :currentState))")
    .withValueMap(
        new ValueMap() 
            .withString(":v_id", "string1") 
            .withString(":version", "CANCELED") 
            .withString(":currentState", "CREATED")
    ); 

ItemCollection<QueryOutcome> items1 = index.query(spec);
```

Comment: as you mentioned i couldnt implement my function like that but that is works for me  QuerySpec spec = new QuerySpec()
                .withKeyConditionExpression("deviceId = :v_id")
                .withFilterExpression("not(contains(currentState, :version) or contains(currentState, :currentState))")
                .withValueMap(new ValueMap()
                        .withString(":v_id", "string1")
                        .withString(":version", "CANCELED")
                        .withString(":currentState", "CREATED"));
        ItemCollection<QueryOutcome> items1 =index.query(spec);

Comment: Agree with you. I have updated the answer for others benefit.